# solve equation using MATLAB solve

Tags: matlab

I have the following equation that I want to solve using MATLAB:

[image]

`X` is the unknown variable. I am trying to solve it using MATLAB `solve`, but I find it hard to code the left part of the equation.

Is it possible to use `solve`? Are there any other options?

**EDIT**

Since `A` and `B` depends respectively on `j` and `i` I have tried to put them in vectors as follows:

```
A = [A(1) ... A(j) ... A(N)]
B = [B(1) ... B(i) ... B(N)]
```

I was trying to have something that looks like this:

```
eqn = sum(A ./ sum(B .* D)) == C;
solve(eqn);
```

but the whole difficulty is in this part:

[image]

because it depends on both `i` and `j`.

Comment: Why is it hard? What have you managed to implement?

Comment: I can do the right side..

Comment: @CrisLuengo I edit my question

Comment: @MartinJames I agree it was silly of me to say that, but I can assure you; I've tried before posting the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write equation you can use this code:

```
syms x real
C = 1;
beta = 10;
alph = 0.5;

N = 10;
lenA = N;
lenB = N;

A = rand(1,N);
B = rand(1,N);

eq = 0;
for j=2:N
    eqaux = 0;
    for i=1:N
        eqaux = eqaux+B(i)/((alph+beta*x)^(i+j+1));
    end
    eq = eq+A(j)/eqaux;
end
eq = simplify(eq==C);
```

If x must be a complex number, delete real of `syms x real`.

To solve the equation use this code:

```
sol = solve(eq,x);
sol = vpa(sol);
```

Of course yu must use your own values of C, alph, beta, A, B and N.

Comment: is it normal that MATLAB takes a lot of time at the ligne `eq = simplify(eq==C);`  ? The length of A and B vectors is 31

Comment: @Afo in general *anything* done with the symbolic toolbox has the potential of being slow. The main problem is that the JIT (basically speed-up engine for MATLAB) doesn't work on symbolic maths. A 31-term equation is rather long AFAIK, so I'd say yes, it's normal.

Comment: Symbolic toolbox is slow, I suggest you to set A and B previously of run _for_ _loops_

Comment: @jualsevi you mean to calculate the elements of A and B out of the loop, I did that. After finishing the variable `sol` was empty, it only shows _sym1x1_ and it gave some warnings.

Comment: @Afo sorry the value of A and B in my code was wrong. I had created A and B matrix using magic, but consider that A and B must be a vector array, I have changed my code to generate A and B using _rand_. I don`t know the values of A and B, is just an example. If I run the code (I just edited A and B), I get _sol_ as a 3 array vector

Comment: @jualsevi I saw that they were matrix, I adapted my code and calculated my own vectors (A & B) and I was expecting to `sol` to be a scalar but it was empty as I said before. Do you mean that the 3 array vector contains the possible solutions or the whole vector is a solution ?

Comment: @Afo I think that is empty because the value of your constant, A and B vectors. If _sol_ is empty, it means that _solve_ has not found a solution. In the case of my code, for that random values of the constants, A and B, there are 3 real solutions; but for another values of constants, solutions number could be more or none

Comment: I think it's the value of C I've given, I'll also check the other parameters and keep you updated

Comment: It's always the same problem, `sol` is empty, but using your example, it's working, I've tried to check the parameters I am using, they seems correct.

Comment: What are the parameterse values? Maybe, I could make test with them.

Comment: @jualsevi it was an error in my formula to get the values of the vector B elements, now it's working  I only have to check if I am getting the correct result

Comment: I'm glad I could help.